# Out of Memory exception BitMapImage for Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am getting  Out of memory exception  in appCapImg.SetSource after picture is clicked two or three times. I tried analyzing with some memory tools but i cant find the problem. Am  i doing something wrong

```
   byte[] data = null;
 public PhotoCamera cam;
 fnInitializeCamera();

      private void fnInitializeCamera()
    {
        gobject.txtMessage.Text = "Tap the screen to capture a photo.";
        if (PhotoCamera.IsCameraTypeSupported(CameraType.Primary) == true)
        {
            cam = new PhotoCamera(CameraType.Primary);
            cam.CaptureImageAvailable += new    EventHandler<Microsoft.Devices.ContentReadyEventArgs>(cam_CaptureImageAvailable);
            gobject.viewfinderBrush.SetSource(cam);
            if (gobject.Orientation == PageOrientation.PortraitUp)
            {
                gobject.viewfinderTransform.Rotation = 90.0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            gobject.txtMessage.Text = "A Camera is not available on this device.";
        }
    }

    public void viewfinder_Tapped(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        gobject.txtMessage.Text = "Saving Image..";
        if (cam != null)
        {
            try
            {
                cam.CaptureImage();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
                {
                    gobject.txtMessage.Text = ex.Message;
                });
            }
        }
    }

private void RotateStream(Stream stream, int angle)
    {


        stream.Position = 0;
        if (angle % 90 != 0 || angle < 0) throw new ArgumentException();
        if (angle % 360 == 0) data= ((MemoryStream)stream).ToArray(); 

        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.DecodePixelWidth = 480;
        bitmap.SetSource(stream);
        stream.Dispose();
        WriteableBitmap wbSource = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);
        bitmap.UriSource = null;

        WriteableBitmap wbTarget = null;
        if (angle % 180 == 0)
        {
            wbTarget = new WriteableBitmap(wbSource.PixelWidth, wbSource.PixelHeight);
        }
        else
        {
            wbTarget = new WriteableBitmap(wbSource.PixelHeight, wbSource.PixelWidth);
        }

        int width = wbSource.PixelWidth;
        int height = wbSource.PixelHeight;
        int targetWidth = wbTarget.PixelWidth;
        int[] sourcePixels = wbSource.Pixels;
        int[] targetPixels = wbTarget.Pixels;

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                switch (angle % 360)
                {
                    case 90:
                        targetPixels[(height - y - 1) + x * targetWidth] = sourcePixels[x + y * width];
                        break;
                    case 180:
                        targetPixels[(width - x - 1) + (height - y - 1) * width] = sourcePixels[x + y * width];
                        break;
                    case 270:
                        targetPixels[y + (width - x - 1) * targetWidth] = sourcePixels[x + y * width];
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        using (MemoryStream targetStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            wbTarget.SaveJpeg(targetStream, width, height, 0, 100);

            data = targetStream.ToArray();

        }
    }

    void cam_CaptureImageAvailable(object sender, Microsoft.Devices.ContentReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        cam.Dispose();
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
        {
            gobject.disableCameraPlugin();
            gobject.enableWebBrowser();
            BitmapImage appCapImg = new BitmapImage();


            if (gobject.Orientation == PageOrientation.PortraitUp)
            {
                RotateStream(e.ImageStream, 90);
              // Stream stream = new MemoryStream(data1);
               using (MemoryStream streamT = new MemoryStream(data))
               {

                   appCapImg.SetSource(streamT);
               }
               data = null;

            }
            else
            {
                RotateStream(e.ImageStream, 180);
                e.ImageStream.Dispose();
                using (MemoryStream streamT = new MemoryStream(data))
                {

                    appCapImg.SetSource(streamT);
                }
                data = null;

            }

            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        WriteableBitmap wBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(appCapImg);
                        appCapImg.UriSource = null;
                        wBitmap.SaveJpeg(stream, wBitmap.PixelWidth, wBitmap.PixelHeight, 0, 40);
                        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        data = stream.ToArray();
                    }
                    string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(data);
                    string[] invokeparam1 = { htmlid, base64 };
                    invokeScript("showimage", invokeparam1);
 }
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete, try pasting again.

Comment: After i converting to base 64 i am returning back to  call back function(written in javascript).

Answer (score 0):

MemoryStream, as I always say, should be handle with care. You can always consider it compulsory to call the dispose on MemoryStream objects after using it. While in the following code you have elegantly handled this issue,

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream()) { .... }
```

You should never returning any Streams directly from a method. There's nothing wrong with it except that it violates the principle you're applying earlier to manually call the Dispose() on all the Stream objects. So you can try returning byte[] instead of a Stream from your method.

```
private Stream RotateStream(Stream stream, int angle)
```

And always include all the stream objects in the using{ ... } block. Again, your code looks incomplete. Like what does the variable "e" stands for.

Comment: I edited my code but no luck. Its still crashing after 4 or 5 pics taken.

Comment: It's definitely a memory issue. As you're loading more images, earlier images are still clogging the memory resulting in this exception. This seems to be a known issue. There are already many articles discussing this issue. What I can suggest is wherever you're using **BitmapImage** make sure to call the **Dispose()**. And for **writeablebitmap** call the **Freeze()**.